# How to save .shp to .csv so that the Name is in the first "column" of the .csv?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, csv

I am trying to convert a point shapefile to .csv with locations in QGIS. The problem I am having with the conversion is mainly that, in the resulting .csv file I would like to have the Name and then Long, Lat, however it constantly comes out as Long, Lat, Name. Is there any way I can save it so that the Name is in the first "column" of the .csv?

Comment: Are you exporting a lot of shapefiles to .csv format? Otherwise you can manually move the column using Microsoft Excel or other software.

Comment: I am using the csv in another software. If i import it into Excel and then export it again some of the locations are changed. I have too many locations to correct them all by hand, hence the question if there was a way of doing it directly in GIS

Answer (score 4):

Try add Long, Lat columns after Name column in attribute table and calculate values via field calculator. When you save to CSV in save Options select GEOMETRY=Defaults (defoults this options set AS_XY) and you receive CSV file with only columns in attribute table of shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the mmqgis plugin?

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/

Comment: +1 From the linked website (note "Column Modification").. `MMQGIS is a set of plugins for manipulating vector map layers in Quantum GIS: CSV input/output/join, Geocoding, Geometry Conversion, Buffering, Hub Analysis, Simplification Column Modification, Color Ramps, and Simple Animation. MMQGIS provides an alternative to the standard QGIS vector plugin sets (fTools and Processing), with verbose progress reporting, an intuitive user interface, direct shapefile/CSV-file access, and some additional capabilities missing from other plugin sets.`